Request failed with status 400 - MSAL-NODE while calling networkClient.sendPostRequestAsync(tokenEndpoint, options)
I have implemented Azure authentiation in web API created in angular 10 application. While authenticating using URL "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" I am getting Request failed with status 400 inside MSAL-NODE while calling networkClient.sendPostRequestAsync(tokenEndpoint, options). Here is detailed error I am getting and code snippet. I am using @azure/msal-node@2.15.0
Code:


async callMSClient(): Promise<any> {
    const msalConfig = {
      auth: {
        clientId: config.get("msConfig.clientId"),
        authority: config.get("msConfig.aadEndPoint") + config.get("msConfig.tenantId"),
        clientSecret: config.get("msConfig.clientSecret"),
        redirectUri: config.get("msConfig.redirectUri"),
        knownAuthorities: ["login.microsoftonline.com"]
      }
    };
    const tokenRequest = {
      scopes: [config.get("msConfig.graphEndPoint") + '.default'],
    };
    const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);
    return cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(tokenRequest).then(data => {
      return data;
    }).catch(e=>{
      console.log(e);
    });
    
  }



Error:
ClientAuthError: network_error: Network request failed
at createClientAuthError (C:\Project\AngTest\node_modules\@azure\msal-common\dist\error\ClientAuthError.mjs:255:12)
at NetworkManager.sendPostRequest (C:\Project\AngTest\node_modules\@azure\msal-common\dist\network\NetworkManager.mjs:35:23)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at ClientCredentialClient.executePostToTokenEndpoint (C:\Project\AngTest\node_modules\@azure\msal-common\dist\client\BaseClient.mjs:79:26)     
at ClientCredentialClient.executeTokenRequest (C:\Project\AngTest\node_modules\@azure\src\client\ClientCredentialClient.ts:295:30)
at ConfidentialClientApplication.acquireTokenByClientCredential (C:\Project\AngTest\node_modules\@azure\src\client\ConfidentialClientApplication.ts:166:20) {

errorCode: 'network_error',
errorMessage: 'Network request failed',
subError: '',
correlationId: 'ef035f69-5522-4224g-633s-ccddd950b2hg'
When I deep dive into error list, while debugging I found two error infact, one is error 400 stating bad request and another is "Self Singed In Certificate Chain" error which seems I have to install a certificate in my local machine for localhost.

Are you trying to generate token using client credentials flow for microsoft graph scope?

@Sridevi Yes, I need auth token which could be used in other calls. Strange part is that when I am calling it from postman, it is returning token but when calling from my API, it is throwing above error.

Any update on the issue?

Here is the alternate for the problem I applied to solution.I acknowldge that @sridevi solution should work mostly but I had another problem also which I found only after deep dive. Posting if someone else is facing similar problem.

Stringify the body before sending to API call.
You can directly call Microsoft Oauth token url using axios.
If you are getting Self Signed in certificate chain error, you can temporarily disable the check using https agent.

Below code worked for me.
I used grant_type:"client_credentials" and added custom agent const agent=new https.Agent({rejectUnauthorized:false}) to disable Self Signed in Certificate chain error. This is not recommended but for testing on localhost it worked for me. In higher environment you should add verified certificate from CA.


async callApi(accessToken) {
    const agent=new https.Agent({rejectUnauthorized:false});
    const url= "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{id}}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        const body = new URLSearchParams({
          client_id: config.get("msConfig.clientId"),
          grant_type:"client_credentials",
          client_secret: config.get("msConfig.clientSecret"),
          scope:"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"  
        })
   
    try {
        const response = await axios.post (url, body, { 
            responseType:"json",
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },httpsAgent: agent});
        
        return {accessToken: response.data.access_token,
            status: response.status
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return error;
    }
}




Initially, I registered one application and granted API permission of Application type as token generation uses client credentials flow:

Now, I ran below commands to create a project and installed dependencies in it:
mkdir azure-auth-node
cd azure-auth-node
npm init -y

npm install @azure/msal-node express dotenv

In my case, I created following code files to generate the token with client credentials flow:
.env:
TENANT_ID=tenantId
CLIENT_ID=appId
CLIENT_SECRET=secret
AUTHORITY=https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId
GRAPH_SCOPE=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

auth.js:
const { ConfidentialClientApplication } = require("@azure/msal-node");
require("dotenv").config();

const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    authority: process.env.AUTHORITY,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  },
};

const tokenRequest = {
  scopes: [process.env.GRAPH_SCOPE], // e.g., https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
};

const cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);

async function getAccessToken() {
  try {
    const response = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(tokenRequest);
    return response.accessToken;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error acquiring token:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

module.exports = { getAccessToken };

index.js:
const express = require("express");
const { getAccessToken } = require("./auth");

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.get("/api/token", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const token = await getAccessToken();
    res.json({ token });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to fetch token" });
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

When I started the server with node index.js command and ran below URL in browser, I got the token successfully as below:
http://localhost:3000/api/token


You can use this token to list users by calling below Microsoft Graph API call:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users



I tried to call the urls from postman and it was returning access_token successfully but from my API it is throwing error. I digged it more and first see bad request and later stuck with "Self Signed in Certificate Chain" error. Seems I need to add a certificate for my localhost inside mmc. Can you help me on that and add steps to add certificate. Well meanwhile I find an alternate for this error.

I voted for your answer.

What do you mean by adding certificate? Could you close this question by clicking the checkmark beside it and post a new one with more details regarding certificate upload part?
